# Problem understanding explanation of why minimizing negative log likelihood gives the same solution as maximizing the likelihood

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

I am having problems following the wording of this explanation.

> Likelihood takes values between 0 and 1. Negative log of this range is
> between $\infty$ and zero. So when we maximise the likelihood it gets
> closer to 1 and when we minimise the negative log likelihood it gets
> closer to 0

"When we maximise the likelihood it gets closer to 1" seems trivial because  "Likelihood takes values between 0 and 1"

"When we minimise the negative log likelihood it gets closer to zero"
Has me puzzled.
Should it be reading "When we minimise the negative log likelihood the *likelihood* gets closer to zero" ?

This is when the likelihood is given by $p(y|\theta)$ with $y$ being the data and $\theta$ being the parameters.

Comment: The statement is correct: the negative logarithm is monotone decreasing, so if you decrease it, you increase the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that the parameter of interest can take only three values and the likelihoods can be ordered

$$
L(\theta_1|X) < L(\theta_3|X) < L(\theta_2|X)
$$

then the opposite is also true

$$
-L(\theta_1|X) > -L(\theta_3|X) > -L(\theta_2|X)
$$

You can extend the example to any number of possible values, including continuous functions. Finding maximum or minimum only cares about such ordering.